# Unix shell scripting - delete multiple lines from a file based on a pattern

Tags: perl, shell, unix, scripting

The format of the file is:

```
header - like 0001datetime|number of records
0010 some data
0012 Roll number (eg)
0020 some data
.
.
.
0070 some data
0010 some data
0012 Roll number (eg)
0020 some data
.
.
.
0070 some data
trailer - like 0099datetime|numberof records
```

**Requirement -** A list of Roll numbers will be given and the the records (0010-0070) needs to be removed for those numbers. There might be any number of fields between **0010** and **0070** but **roll number is always at 0012**.

Each record always starts with 0010 and end with 0070.

Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: hve tried to use awk to create a pattern but since the number of lines between the records vary, not able to get a proper output

Answer (score 0):

Aside of header and trailer line, your file consists of blocks. Each block starts with a 0010 line and ends with a 0070 line.

One straightforward algorithm would be to always read one whole block into memory, and write it out only if the 0012 line (denoting the roll number) is not one of the roll numbers to be deleted.

You are tagging this question by "shell". However, while a solution using just, i.e., bash or zsh is technically possible, I think it's much easier to use a more flexible language for this - Ruby, Perl, Python etc.  Maybe you can tag the problem with the language of your choice?

If you are not familiar yet with one of those languages, my personal recommendation would be Ruby, because I find it quick to learn; but all of them are equally well suitable for this problem.

Comment: I have some knowledge of perl though not as advanced as to write something like this.. Do you have any command or set of commands in mind, so that I can look it up?

Comment: And also I need to embed it into unix script as that is the requirement, but I know we can embed a perl script into it

Comment: @SanMani: I suggest you start writing the Perl program and post in a separate posting (tagged with 'perl') where you get stuck. You can find for instance [here](http://perlmaven.com/open-and-read-from-files) how to process a file using Perl: